# How do I stop a Camel route when JVM gets to a certain heap size?

Tags: java, jvm, apache-camel, heap-memory

I am using Apache Camel to connect to various endpoints, including JMS topics, and write to a database. Sometimes the database connection fails (for whatever reason, database issue, network blip, etc) and the messages from the topic subscriber start backing up. At a certain point, there are so many messages backed up waiting to be written to the database that the application throws an out of memory error. So far I understand all that.

The problem I have is the following: When the application is frantically trying to garbage collect before eventually giving up and accepting that it is out of memory, the application stops working, but is still alive. This means that the topic subscriber is still seen as active by the JMS provider, but not reading anything off the topic, so the provider starts queueing up the messages. Eventually the provider falls over also when the maximum depth runs out.

How can I configure my application to either disconnect when reaching a certain heap usage, or kill itself completely much much faster when running out of memory? I believe there are some JVM parameters that allow the application to kill itself much quicker when running out of memory, but I am wondering if that is the best solution or whether there is another way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can control (start/stop and suspend/resume) Camel routes using the Camel context methods `.stop()`, `.start()`, `.suspend()` and `.resume()`.

You can spin a separate thread that monitors the current VM memory and stops the required route when a certain condition is met.

```
new Thread() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        while(true) {
            long free = Runtime.getRuntime().freeMemory();
            boolean routeRunning = camelContext.isRouteStarted("yourRoute");
            if (free < threshold && routeRunning) {
                camelContext.stopRoute("yourRoute");
            } else if (free > threshold && !routeRunning) {
                camelContext.startRoute("yourRoute");
            }
            // Check every 10 seconds
            Thread.sleep(10000);
        }
    }
}
```

As commented in the other answer, relying on this is not particularly robust, but at least a little more robust than getting an OutOfMemoryException. Note that you need to `.stop()` the route, `.suspend()` does not deallocate resources, which means the connection with the queue provider is still open and the service looks like it is open for business.

You can also stop the route as part of the error handling of the route itself (this is possibly more robust but would require manual intervention to restart the route once the error is cleared, or a scheduled route that periodically checks if the error condition still exists and restart the route if it is gone). The thing to keep in mind is that you cannot stop a route from the same thread that is servicing the route at the time so you need to spin a separate thread that does the stopping. For example:

```
route("sample").from("jms://myqueue")
    // Handle SQL Exceptions by shutting down the route
    .onException(SQLException.class)
        .process(new Processor() {
            // This processor spawns a new thread that stops the current route
            Thread stop;

            @Override
            public void process(final Exchange exchange) throws Exception {
                if (stop == null) {
                    stop = new Thread() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            try {
                                // Stop the current route
                                exchange.getContext().stopRoute("sample");
                            } catch (Exception e) {}
                        }
                    };
                }
                // start the thread in background
                stop.start();
            }
        })
    .end()
    // Standard route processors go here
    .to(...);
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all I think you should use a JDBC connection pool that is capable of refreshing failed connections. So you do not run into the described scenario in the first place. At least not if the DB/network issue is short lived.

Next I'd protect the message broker by applying producer flow control (at least thats how it is called in ActiveMQ). I.e. prevent message producers from submitting more messages if a certain memory threshold has been breached. If the thresholds are set correctly, then that will prevent your message broker from falling over.

As for your original question: I'd use JMX to monitor the VM. If some metric, e.g. memory, breaches a threshold then you can suspend or shut down the route or the whole Camel context via the MBeans Camel exposes.

Comment: Thanks Ralf. Unfortunately on my current project (it's a very large company, with tons of paperwork) I am forced to use a hibernate config I've been given, and the message broker that is available. I will enquire as to getting them to set up the equivalent of 'flow control' though. For monitoring the VM, is it possible for the VM to monitor itself? Could there be a Camel mechanism for doing this out of the box? Or would it have to be a separate VM doing the monitoring over JMX?

Comment: Yes, you can monitor yourself, but I doubt that it will be very robust. You need action taken when the VM gets under load. Meaning the process that needs to take action is then part of the VM that already is overloaded. Many monitoring tools, e.g. [Hyperic](http://www.hyperic.com/), allow you to monitor VM metrics via JMX and to automatically trigger an action, e.g. call a method on an MBean, if thresholds are breached. Maybe you should talk to your operations guys what kinds of tools they use to monitor your production environment.